# SMTP client in C blocks on SSL_read

Tags: c, email, openssl, smtp

I have been working on a small project which is a SMTP client written in C with SSL.

I am trying to get it working with GMail. I have enabled the **allow unsecure apps** in GMail settings.

When I try to authenticate using the OpenSSL CLI with the command `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465` it works just fine I get proper responses for HELO and EHLO commands (see the output below)

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o3-v6sm18136158pgv.53 - gsmtp
HELO smtp.gmail.com
250 smtp.gmail.com at your service
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
```

But once I run this with my C client it hangs on SSL_read after I send `HELO smtp.gmail.com` and it does not even give me any output for `HELO smtp.gmail.com`.

But if I send just `HELO` I get a proper response from the server saying that **empty HELO isn't allowed**

## MAIN

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    setup("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
    printf("[INFO] -- %s\n", recv_secure());
    send_secure("HELO smtp.gmail.com\r\n");
    printf("[INFO] -- %s\n", recv_secure());
    send_secure("AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
    printf("[INFO] -- %s\n", recv_secure());
    close_secure();
    return 0;
}
```

## setup

```
int setup(char *hostname, int port) {
    SSL_CTX *ctx = init();

    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int sock_fd;

    if((host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] Unable to get host by name: %s", hostname);
        return -1;
    }

    sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)host->h_addr_list[0];

    if(connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        close(sock_fd);
        fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] Unable to connect to remote server: %s\n", hostname);
        return -1;
    }

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock_fd);

    if(SSL_connect(ssl) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] Unable to establish secure connection\n");
        close(sock_fd);
        return -1;
    }
    return sock_fd;
}
```

## send_secure

```
void send_secure(const char* buffer){
    SSL_write(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
}
```

## recv_secure

```
char* recv_secure() {

    int bytes = SSL_read(ssl, rbuffer, SIZE);
    rbuffer[bytes] = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "[DEBUG] -- Received: %s\n", rbuffer);
    return rbuffer;
}
```

I ran ltrace with it and it seems to be blocked at `SSL_read` but `SSL_pending` **return value is 0**

I cannot seem to understand what am I missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> void send_secure(const char* buffer){
>   SSL_write(ssl, mbuffer, sizeof(mbuffer));
> }
> ```

Assuming that `mbuffer` is a typo and `buffer` was meant instead, this will write either 8 or 4 bytes (the size of a pointer, depending on your platform), not the length of the buffer as you probably expected (which will be wrong, too since `sizeof`, when applied to a literal string, also includes the terminating null byte -- which will NOT be accepted by the smtp server).

Changing `sizeof` to `strlen` may let you proceed further, but your code has a lot of problems, for instance:

> ```
> int bytes = SSL_read(ssl, rbuffer, SIZE);
> rbuffer[bytes] = 0;
> ```

If `SSL_read` returns -1, this will (in the best case ;-)) crash your program.

Comment: Yep that worked, thanks for pointing out the `SSL_read` issue, I'll fix that and also the typo in the question in the `send_secure` function